# How std::bind can be used?

Tags: c++, bind, std

One simple example that explains how `std::bind` can be used is as follows:

Assume that we have a function of 3 arguments: f3(x, y, z). We want to have a function of 2 arguments that is defined as: `f2(x,y) = f3(x,5,y)`. In C++ we can easily do it with `std::bind`:

```
auto f2 = std::bind(f3, _1, 5, _2);
```

This example is clear to me: `std::bind` takes a function as its first argument and then it takes n other arguments, where n is the number of arguments of the function that is taken as the first argument for `std::bind`.

However, I found another use of bind:

```
void foo( int &x )
{
  ++x;
}


int main()
{
  int i = 0;

  // Binds a copy of i
  std::bind( foo, i ) (); // <------ This is the line that I do not understand.
  std::cout << i << std::endl;

}
```

It is clear that `foo` has one argument and with `std::bind` it was set to `i`. But but why do we use another pair of brackets after `(foo, i)`? And why we do not use output of the `std::bind`? I mean, why don't we have `auto f = std::bind(foo, i)`?

Comment: What on earth is `\\\`?

Comment: It was supposed to be a comment: //

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The line

```
std::bind( foo, i ) ();
```

is equivalent to:

```
auto bar = std::bind( foo, i );
bar();
```

It creates a bound functor, then immediately calls it (using the second pair of parenthesis).

Edit: In the name of accuracy (and pointed out by @Roman, @daramarak) the two are not *actually* equivalent to calling the function directly: the i is passed by value to std::bind. The code equivalent to calling `foo` directly with i, would be:

```
auto bar = std::bind( foo, std::ref(i) );
bar();
```

Comment: Removed my comments about an invalid objection

Answer (score 3):

It binds `foo` to a temporary object and then call it immediately:

```
  auto f = std::bind(foo, i);
  f();
```

Single line version:

```
std::bind(foo, i)();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your two questions pretty much answer each other. The trailing `()` is just a normal function call. Therefore, the expression means: "Bind `i` to `foo`; this will yield a function taking no parameters; then call the resulting function." Since the code's author decided the function is no longer needed after being called, it's not stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Since the line

```
std::bind( foo, i ) () ;
```

... does the same thing as ...

```
foo(i);
```

... this isn't really a 'use' of std::bind which you might encounter in actual code, but it does serve as a simple illustration of what std::bind does, as explained in other answers.

As you point out, it's the usual case to store the result of the bind and call it somewhere else, otherwise there's no point in complicating the code with a std::bind in the first place.